# What is crystal "supermodulation"?

Tags: superconductivity, crystals

I am researching the pair density wave in cuprates, and during my reading I came across a term "crystal supermodulation". I believe it relates to BSCCO. Can anyone give me a definition or give me a reference?

Comment: Quasiperiodic variations of unit cell geometry. See http://www.pnas.org/content/105/9/3203.full

Comment: @mmesser314 Thank you, this is what I was looking for.